Flatlist scrolling to top onEndReached on state update
I have TabView and Flatlists in each TabView. In flatlist prop onReachEnd a function is called to update a state. As soon as onRecahEnd is executed flatlist scrolled to to top even though I am not calling any API yet. The state is updating correctly but dont know why it is scrolling to top every single time.
const Pending = ({orderData, loading, onEndReached}: any) => (
  <>
    {loading ? (
      <View style={[styles.tabContainer]}>
        <View style={{flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
          <ActivityIndicator color={COLORS.ACCENT} size={50} />
        </View>
      </View>
    ) : (
      <FlatList
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        data={orderData}
        renderItem={({item}) => <RenderItem item={item} />}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${item.id}-${index}`}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.flatListContent}
        ListEmptyComponent={
          !loading ? (
            <View style={styles.emptyContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.emptyText}>No pending orders available.</Text>
            </View>
          ) : null
        }
        onEndReached={onEndReached}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
        // ListFooterComponent={
        //   loadingMore && (
        //     <View style={styles.footerLoading}>
        //       <ActivityIndicator color={COLORS.ACCENT} size={40} />
        //     </View>
        //   )
        // }
      />
    )}
  </>
);

const Order = ({navigation}: any) => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const [orderData, setOrderData] = useState([]);
  const {localData} = useContext<any>(AuthContext);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  const dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>();

  const tabs = [
    {key: 'pending', title: 'Pending'},
    {key: 'confirmed', title: 'Confirmed'},
    {key: 'all', title: 'All'},
  ];

  const statusMap = ['pending', 'confirm', 'all'];

  const renderScenes = {
    pending: () => (
      <Pending
        loading={loading}
        orderData={orderData}
        onEndReached={handleEndReached}
      />
    ),
    confirmed: () => <Confirmed loading={loading} orderData={orderData} />,
    all: () => <All loading={loading} orderData={orderData} />,
  };

  const fetchOrders = async (status: string) => {
    if (localData) {
      try {
        setOrderData([]);
        const resp = await dispatch(
          ordersByPagination({
            data: {
              url: localData?.base_url,
              skip: 0,
              take: 10,
              apiVersion: localData?.api_version,
              status: status,
            },
          }),
        );
        setOrderData(resp?.payload);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching orders:', error);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }
  };

  let status;
  useEffect(() => {
    status = statusMap[index];

    fetchOrders(status);
  }, [index]);

  const handleEndReached = () => {
    setPage(prevPage => prevPage + 1);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <StatusBar
        backgroundColor={COLORS.NEUTRAL_LIGHT}
        barStyle={'dark-content'}
      />
      <Header onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()} title="Order History" />
      <View style={styles.tabContainer}>
        <TabView
          index={index}
          setIndex={setIndex}
          tabBarStyle={{marginHorizontal: 0, marginBottom: 5}}
          tabs={tabs}
          renderScenes={renderScenes}
        />
      </View>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};


Changes:

Avoid resetting orderData. Instead, append new data to it when loading more items.
Fix keyExtractor to ensure unique keys for each item in the FlatList.
Handle pagination correctly by using the page state to load more items as the user scrolls.



    const Pending = ({orderData, loading, onEndReached}: any) => (
      <>
        {loading ? (
          <View style={[styles.tabContainer]}>
            <View style={{flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
              <ActivityIndicator color={COLORS.ACCENT} size={50} />
            </View>
          </View>
        ) : (
          <FlatList
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            data={orderData}
            renderItem={({item}) => <RenderItem item={item} />}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${item.id}-${index}`}
            contentContainerStyle={styles.flatListContent}
            ListEmptyComponent={
              !loading ? (
                <View style={styles.emptyContainer}>
                  <Text style={styles.emptyText}>No pending orders available.</Text>
                </View>
              ) : null
            }
            onEndReached={onEndReached}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
          />
        )}
      </>
    );
    
    const Order = ({navigation}: any) => {
      const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
      const [orderData, setOrderData] = useState([]);
      const {localData} = useContext<any>(AuthContext);
      const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
      const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
      const dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
    
      const tabs = [
        {key: 'pending', title: 'Pending'},
        {key: 'confirmed', title: 'Confirmed'},
        {key: 'all', title: 'All'},
      ];
    
      const statusMap = ['pending', 'confirm', 'all'];
    
      const renderScenes = {
        pending: () => (
          <Pending
            loading={loading}
            orderData={orderData}
            onEndReached={handleEndReached}
          />
        ),
        confirmed: () => <Confirmed loading={loading} orderData={orderData} />,
        all: () => <All loading={loading} orderData={orderData} />,
      };
    
      const fetchOrders = async (status: string) => {
        if (localData) {
          try {
            const resp = await dispatch(
              ordersByPagination({
                data: {
                  url: localData?.base_url,
                  skip: page * 10, // Adjust skip for pagination
                  take: 10,
                  apiVersion: localData?.api_version,
                  status: status,
                },
              }),
            );
            setOrderData(prevData => [...prevData, ...resp?.payload]); // Append new data
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching orders:', error);
          } finally {
            setLoading(false);
          }
        }
      };
    
      let status;
      useEffect(() => {
        status = statusMap[index];
        fetchOrders(status);
      }, [index]);
    
      const handleEndReached = () => {
        setPage(prevPage => prevPage + 1); // Increment page number
      };
    
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <StatusBar
            backgroundColor={COLORS.NEUTRAL_LIGHT}
            barStyle={'dark-content'}
          />
          <Header onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()} title="Order History" />
          <View style={styles.tabContainer}>
            <TabView
              index={index}
              setIndex={setIndex}
              tabBarStyle={{marginHorizontal: 0, marginBottom: 5}}
              tabs={tabs}
              renderScenes={renderScenes}
            />
          </View>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    };



This should now be correctly formatted, and I hope it helps resolve the issue!
